# Is there a list of skippable fairy tail episodes to just watch the main plot

Tags: fairy-tail

I'm really far behind on fairy tail, is there a list of plot episodes I could watch. and I mean Plot not just canon and filler episodes

Comment: Skippable or not depends on the taste of the person watching. Your question is opinion based IMHO.

Comment: Questions somewhat like this have been asked on SFF.SE with regards to Star Trek, but they usually focused specifically on which episodes were essential to understand later episodes. If you could narrow this down to something like "Which episodes of Fairy Tail do I need to watch to understand [whatever the current arc is]?", it might be permissible, as that can be answered more or less objectively. For now I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: highly recommend you to do not skip filler ,because even though its filler characters on filler episodes  or arcs are reoccurring.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly look into this link for the same.

http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/fairy-tail

```
Filler Episodes:9, 19, 49-50, 69-75, 125-150, 204-226  
Canon Episodes:1-8, 10-18, 20-48, 51-68, 76-124, 151-203, 227-233
```